# Hard time with Derivatives of Inverse Functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, inverse

I'm having a really hard time with this question I keep googling for advice but can't find anything solid that's similar! Please help. I'm not sure if I should derive first or find the inverse first? And also: I am not sure what to do with the $f(0)=2$ information.

calculate 
$$(f^{-1})'(2)$$
       while
$$f(0) = 2$$

$$f(x)=4x^3+2 \sin x+2 \cos x$$

I'm really not sure how to go about answering this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that, by the chain rule
$$
  1
= \frac{d}{dx}x
= \frac{d}{dx}f(f^{-1}(x))
= f'(f^{-1}(x))\left( \frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x)\right)
$$
to conclude that 
$$
  \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)
= \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.
$$
You are asked to find $(f^{-1})'(2)$ which you can now see is just 
$\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(2))}$. So you should find $f'$ and apply it to $f^{-1}(2)$, which you are told is $0$:
$$
  (f^{-1})'(2)
= \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(2))}
= \frac{1}{f'(0)}
= (\left.12x^2 + 2\cos x - 2\sin x \right|_{x=0})^{-1}
= 1/2.
$$

Comment: ohhhh i see! thank you!

Comment: @maribov no problem. Note that you don't need to actually find the inverse function in these kinds of problems, only the inverse at the given point. Finding the inverse would have been intractible